# REM for element sizing not working below font-size 50% in webkit

Tags: css, webkit, font-size

I've started using REMs to size certain elements on a page so that I can easily adjust their size across the board just by modifying the font-size on the root html element (useful for media queries). However, I've noticed an issue in desktop webkit browsers where the elements will resize to match any font-size above 50%, but not any further below.

[You can see an example of it happening on this page](http://jsbin.com/yapaviqu/1/edit?html,css,output) showing off the technique of sizing elements with REMs. I've also included the example code below.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block"></div> 
    <p>Sample Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {font-size: 62.5%}
p {font-size: 2rem;}
.block {background: yellow; width: 10em; height: 10em;}

@media (min-width: 600px) {html {font-size: 70%}}
@media (min-width: 700px) {html {font-size: 80%}}
@media (max-width: 400px) {html {font-size: 50%}}
@media (max-width: 300px) {html {font-size: 40%}}
@media (max-width: 200px) {html {font-size: 30%}}
```

You can see the box, which is set at 10rem at font-size: 62.5%, render at 100px square. As you scale up the base font-size (via media queries), the box get's bigger as expected. The box also shrinks down to font-size 50%, but any value below that, the box never gets smaller than 50%. (Text sizes continue to scale down though).

Firefox continues to shrink the box below 50% (haven't tested IE), so this is likely a webkit only issue.

-webkit-text-size-adjust: none works for mobile webkit, but doesn't have any effect on the desktop versions.

As anyone else encountered this issue, and devised a solution?

Comment: Include code that demonstrates what you are talking about, and nothing more. A jsbin link is a nice extra, but not sufficient. In this case, there is a lot of code there that does not seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for your response. I've updated the jsbin link to a new one that only includes what's needed to demonstrate the bug, and also edited my original post to include the code inline.

Comment: This seems to depend on minimum font size rather than the use of the `rem` unit. Chrome does not let the user set minimum font size smaller than 6px (rather reasonable, since text is hardly readable in smaller size).

Comment: I thought that, but the text continues to reduce in size below 50%. To get around this, I've ended up making the base font size 625%, and then making all rem values a tenth of what they were. Not ideal, but it'll do the job.